# How to modify the controls of React Player while playing the mp4 file. I want the option of getting downloaded be disabled

Tags: reactjs, react-player

[I want to remove the option of the marked circle in the image from the player so that video can't be downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SwS1.png)

Comment: Hey @Govind can you provide us more information like source code, website you are referring to. The image you have provided doesn't give any information to help you.

Comment: <ReactPlayer
          url='https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4'
          className='react-player'
          controls
          width='100%'
          height='100%'
        />

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add `controlsList="nodownload"` to the `video` element and the download button will disappear in Chrome.

Keep in mind that people can still download the video if they really want to. An additional precaution would be to disable right-clicking on the video element:

```js
<ReactPlayer
  // Disable download button
  config={{ file: { attributes: { controlsList: 'nodownload' } } }}

  // Disable right click
  onContextMenu={e => e.preventDefault()}

  // Your props
  url="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4"
  className="react-player"
  controls
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
/>
```

Comment: Hey @Fabian Can you please tell me how can I disable right click on videos in ReactJS

Comment: @GovindMaheshwari Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: very useful. Thanks

Comment: This line isn't working for me, download is still in the menu
config={{ file: { attributes: { controlsList: 'nodownload' } } }}